# Django BooleanField always checked even when value is false

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a BooleanField in a standard Django Form defined as:

```
my_boolean_field = BooleanField(initial=True)
```

when I render my form with initial data, and my_boolean_field is set to an initial value of False, when the form renders it is still checked despite the fact that the value is false as the html shows:

```
<p><label for="id_2">my_boolean_field</label>: 
    <input checked="checked" 
           type="checkbox" 
           name="2" 
           value="False" 
           id="id_2" /> 
</p>
```

Has anyone else experienced this, or knows how to fix it so that when the initial data/input value is false then the checkbox is not checked?

UPDATE: Even if I remove the initial=True argument from the BooleanField the same thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can't have `required=False` on a `BooleanField`, use `NullBooleanField` instead:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField

let me know what the HTML output of the new widget is once you've done this?

## EDIT

I assumed that this is a ModelForm. Is this a regular django.forms.Form?

## EDIT 2

My test form:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form) :
    """The test form"""
    my_boolean_field = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)
```

My template:

```
<div>
{{ form.my_boolean_field.label_tag }}
{{ form.my_boolean_field }}
{{ form.my_boolean_field.errors }}
</div>
```

This is what I get for output when I view page source. **EDITED**

```
<div>
<label for="id_my_boolean_field">My boolean field</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_boolean_field" id="id_my_boolean_field" />
</div>
```

My View **NEW**

```
form = MyForm(initial={'my_boolean_field':False})
```

What you are showing and what I'm seeing aren't matching up. paste your full form, view and template please?

## EDIT 3

I only see output like this:

```
<div>
<label for="id_my_boolean_field">My boolean field</label>
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="my_boolean_field" value="False" id="id_my_boolean_field" />
</div>
```

when I put False in quotes:

```
form = FormLogin(initial={'my_boolean_field':"False"})
```

Comment: this is a standard Form, and actually my field is required so I have edited my question, to removed required=False, but I am still getting the same behaviour

Comment: are you creating your form with initial data, eg. `form = MyForm(initial={'my_boolean_field':False}) `

Comment: AHHHHH that is the problem, i was actually generating the initial data dynamically and the boolean values were getting cast to strings!! Thanks a lot that was a really good spot!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this answer because I had the same problem and Francis's answer didn't help me.

I eventually found the solution was to re-run `manage.py syncdb`.  My fields had previously been IntegerField and I had converted them to BooleanField.  BooleanField read the presence of value="0" in the database as being initialized and checked.  This is regardless of what your model says.  You want to see:

```
<input checked="checked" id="id_cost_track_destruction" name="cost_track_destruction" type="checkbox">
```

when you inspect an element.  Since this bug shows up in the Django Admin panel, it has nothing to do with your forms.py.

This is purely a model and database issue.  Try regenerating your database if you've changed your models.py field types.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using ModelForms, this is what worked for me:

```
password_required = forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'checked' : ''})
```

This correctly generates the checkbox with it unchecked.